# reversing an object literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

I have a jQuery plugin where one of the options ('inits') the user can pass in is an array

the array can contain any of these values

space, tab, enter, comma

Now I have an object literal called keys that looks like

```
keys: {
        backspace: 8,
        enter:     13,
        space:     32,
        comma:     44,
        tab:       9
    }
```

I have a keydown handler

in the keydown handler I want to check if the key that was pressed is in the inits array.
Now to do this I need to first map the key backwards in the keys array so I can get the name from the code.

How would I do this?

Comment: Note that I do not want to have two copies of the keys object, and I cannot write the objct backwards as it is used in other places in its current form.

Comment: "used in other places in its current form"? Sounds like a possible violation of DRY. If it's practical to rewrite so that you only have it once, I would recommend that. Then you'd have a few more ways of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keyName = ""
for( var key in keys ){ if( keys[key] == keyCode ){ keyName = key } }

if( $.inArray( keyName, inits ) != -1 ){ //do something }
```

Comment: Iteration isn't so bad when you only have five elements.

Comment: In fact, any code which flips the map will most certainly be slower than this implementation.